# Is hooky a proper word

Tags: word-meaning, american-english

I was looking into the word `hook` one of the meanings of this word is to catch attention.
So could I say that the marketing campaign is very `hooky`? Is that a correct word? Any alternative word etc.

Comment: ***hookey*** is colloquial American English for BrE ***truant*** (in both cases, *"**played**"* unauthorised absence from school).

Comment: It brings to mind [hokey](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/hokey), though the implication is different from what you're looking for.

Comment: Welcome to ELL rohit! Have you tried a dictionary? This site is a place to ask questions you can't get answers to in normal references like dictionaries. If you have, please tell us what you found and why you're still unsure. [How do I ask a good question?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

"Hooky" is a word, but it doesn't mean what you want to say. 'Hooky' means that something is *shaped like a hook* (ie 'bent'). Further, in British English slang, 'hooky' means *suspect, stolen, dodgy*, likely because of the fact that 'bent' can also mean illegal or corrupt.

The word I think you need is '*[catchy](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/catchy)*'. Cambridge dictionary defines 'catchy' as "*catchy music or words are pleasing and easy to remember, like the sort often used in advertising*".

Comment: *Au contraire* - [the definition in M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hooky) includes "*music* : appealing and easy to remember : CATCHY".  For example, [Here's the Simple Secret of 'Hooky' Songs](https://blog.sonicbids.com/songwriting-101-simple-secret-hooky-songs)  and [Tips for Adding Hooky Rhythms to Your Music Tracks](https://www.bmi.com/news/entry/percussion-primer-tips-for-adding-hooky-rhythms-to-your-music-tracks).  So I don't think it's such a stretch to extend its meaning.

Comment: @stangdon Not really contrary at all, as that use is exclusive to music. I'm a songwriter myself so I'm more than aware of this meaning. We speak about *musical hooks* as well as *lyrical hooks*. But I feel it would be misleading to include in my answer here because it isn't used anywhere else, and while you might think its okay to stretch the meaning, a whole lot of British English speakers, along with anyone else looking in British English dictionaries for a meaning to this word in the context of advertising, would default to the definition I mention before your leap of logic.